# Actual processing time of hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, jobs, cloudera

My cluster is currently occupied by a job `A` that takes long time and has *VERY_LOW* priority.

I started another job `B` yesterday while `A` was already running and I think it should have ran quite fast.
However, I saw it took 47 minutes at the job details.
I don't think this is the actual processing time.
I'm trying to find out when the job really started.
Where can I look?

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to know the actual time spent on that process alone, i.e. not just time finished minus time started but only time spent on the process itself? Also, did you have any other jobs running at the same time?

Comment: Right, that's what I tried to say. I edited my question, so maybe it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I cant seem to find anywhere which states exactly what you're after, but you could look into the job in the job tracker on port 50030 and look at the individual mapper and reducer details. On there you can see how long each individual mapper and reducer took to complete their tasks from their start and end times.

If there weren't any mappers or reducers free when you started the second job, the second job wouldnt be able to make any progress until the first job released them, which might explain why it claimed to take so long, as they might not have actually been running simultaneously. The time of the job being started and the first actual mapper starting should give you an indication of whether it was just waiting around for resources, which means you can deduct the period of time between the job and mapper's start times from the overall 47 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately it was a streaming job without a reducer, so all 47 Minutes were used by one single map task attempt. Looks like it simply can't be seen.